# Log4net Rolling by Date

Tags: log4net

I require the log4net to create date wise with log file name as "Application.20130125.txt", format of "Application.yyyyMMdd.txt" at the time of creating log file instead at the time of date changing at night 12 AM.

And when the date changes, it should create new logfile as "Application.20130126.txt"

Could you please suggest what changes need to be done to the
below code so that the date is created first and at the time of rolling,
creates a new file with the date "Application.20130126.txt"

```
            LogPath = "C:\Logs\"
            fileName = "ApplicationName" & "..txt"

            hierarchy = DirectCast(LogManager.GetRepository(), Hierarchy)
    patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%m%n"
    patternLayout.ActivateOptions()
    roller.Layout = patternLayout
    roller.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Date
    roller.DatePattern = "yyyyMMdd"
    roller.AppendToFile = True
    roller.StaticLogFileName = True
    roller.File = LogPath & fileName
    roller.PreserveLogFileNameExtension = True
    roller.ActivateOptions()
    hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(roller)
    hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.Debug
    hierarchy.Configured = True
    log = LogManager.GetLogger("RollingFileAppender")
```

Comment: You would need to add the rolling style to Date along with the pattern and automatically it would roll over the log to a new file name when the date boundary changes. Check this link: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.html

Comment: Also have a look at this link on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734963/log4net-rollingfileappender-with-composite-rolling-style-is-overwritting-data

Comment: I want the DatePattern to work at the time of creation of file but not while rolling at 12 AM midnight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find my sample below that i have used that would write to the file as you need:

```
    Dim fileappender = New log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender()
    fileappender.AppendToFile = True
    fileappender.Threshold = log4net.Core.Level.Debug
    fileappender.File = "MyLogFile_"
    fileappender.DatePattern = "yyyyMMdd"
    fileappender.StaticLogFileName = False
    fileappender.Layout = New log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout()
    fileappender.RollingStyle = log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Date
    fileappender.ActivateOptions()
    DirectCast(log4net.LogManager.GetRepository(), log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy).Root.AddAppender(fileappender)
    log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(fileappender)
```

The above would create a log file with its filename as "MyLogFile_20130125" today 
and once the date time changes it would write a new file as "MyLogFile_20130126"

You can alternatively test it by setting the datePattern to `"yyyyMMddhhmm"` and that would write a new log file each minute.

Comment: I am using log4net for Windows Service with attribute set as <MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)> _ for OnElapsedTime(). With this it should create only one thread. But still it is creating multiple log files randomly as "MyLogFile_20130125", "MyLogFile_2013012520130125", "MyLogFile_201301252013012520130125". It keeps on appending the yyyyMMdd to the log file name even though the date is not changed. Is there any solution?